# manipulate single angle in polygon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[follow up for prior question in this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2058065/399067)

In an arbitrary polygon represented in a $x-y$ coordinate plane, the angle of a selected intersection is changed by a small increment. Before the change, all points for the polygon are known and all segment lengths are known as are their inclination measured relative to a zero position for $3$ o'clock. After a new angle has been imposed on a given intersection (P#3 in the diagram) we want to find new coordinates for the altered intersection. We apply the following constraints:

$1)$ no other intersection in the polygon will change position.

$2)$ the altered intersection will remain on the same line which the original intersection delimited as normal to a line between its adjacent intersections. (the red line in the diagram shows this normal line; the dashed line shows the line between adjacent intersections P#1 and P#2)

explanatory diagram [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWoLz.png)

The values for A and B in the diagram remain constant and calculable. The value for the sum of angles a and b are known (the new imposed angle for the intersection). The value for C will depend upon this sum (a+b) and if we can determine C for any value of a+b, we can compute the required x-y coordinates for the new position of the intersection.

The problem is that while we know the value $a+b$, and we can deduce that:

$\tan(a)/\tan(b) = A/B$ (a known value)

we need to know angle $a$ (or $b$) to solve for $C$.

Is this doable ?

I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a+b=c$ (known value) and $A/B=r$: we have then

$$
{\tan(c-b)\over\tan b}=r.
$$
Using the tangent subtraction formula this becomes:
$$
\tan c-\tan b=r\tan b(1+\tan c\tan b),
$$
which is a quadratic equation in $\tan b$, easy to solve:
$$
\tan b={\sqrt{(1+r)^2+4r\tan^2c}-r-1\over 2r\tan c}.
$$

Comment: This solution was elegant and comprehensive, a highly enabling assist and a whole other world of knowledge and skill.